# Как закрыть диалоговое окно при выходе из Activity?

Tags: android, android-dialog

Подскажите, как это правильно должно быть? Вызываю диалог при переходе с одного активити в другое. И в момент, пока система думает, решил запустить диалоговое окно. Но, когда активити finish(), в логах, я заметил ошибку.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            ProgressDialog dialog2 = new ProgressDialog(EmailPasswordActivity.this);
            dialog2.setTitle("");
            dialog2.setMessage("Секунду...");
            dialog2.show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(EmailPasswordActivity.this, MainList.class);
            intent.putExtra("email", ETemail.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("username", username.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("userage", userage.getText().toString());
            saveText();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            EmailPasswordActivity.this.finish();

        }
```

Я понимаю, что диалог необходимо закрыть. Но где и когда, по какой логике. Или вообще все не так?

Comment: Какую ошибку вы заметили? И я правильно понял, что вы хотите показывать диалог пока открывается другая активити? Если да, то это, вроде, невозможно.

Comment: Получается, что да. Пока не открылась новая активность, диалог работает, как только она открылась, диалог закрылся. Ошибка простая, пишет что в строке dialog.show() косяк

Comment: Мне просто еще необходимо было при переходе закрыть полностью активность. Я вызвал finish() при переходе. И тогда появилась ошибка по диалогу. По сути ни на что не влияет, и все работает, но так не должно быть я дкмаю.

Comment: И вот еще... Добавил простой диалог а не прогресс, и все ок, нет ошибки

Comment: Не понятно, что у вас за ошибка - времени исполнения, этапа компиляции или просто предупреждение от статического анализатора в IDE? Без этой информации сложно понять есть ли у вас проблема и если есть - то какая.

Comment: В onStop() активити, создавший диалог выполнить dialog2.dismiss() .

Comment: at com.whitelynx.trengym.EmailPasswordActivity$2.onClick(EmailPasswordActivity.java:127) вот это в логах, что в этой строчке у меня косяк, а в этой строчке у меня dialog.show()

Comment: Всем спаибо))) вопрос закрыт. Разбил код, часть перед onCreat, часть  onCreat, а show и dissmiss соответственно.